# SAS date conversion from text.

Tags: date, sas

Hi I have a date conversion problem in SAS, 
I imported an excel file which has the following dates.,

```
2012-01-09
2011-01-31
2010-06-28
2005-06-10
2012-09-19
2012-09-19
2007-06-12
2012-09-20
2004-11-01
2007-03-27
2008-06-23
2006-04-20
2012-09-20
2010-07-14
```

after I imported the dates have changed like this

```
40917
40574
40357
38513
41171
41171
39245
41172
38292
39168
39622
38827
41172
40373
```

I have used the input function to convert the dates but it gives a strange result., 
the code I used.,

```
want_date=input(have_date, anydtdte12.);
informat want_date date9.; format have_date date9.;run;
```

I get very stange and out of the World dates., any idea how can I convert these?

Comment: Can you explain more clearly what the issue is here? Are the 5-digit numbers you are listing the data after import into SAS? What is the format/informat of that field?

Comment: The numbers are Excel's numeric representation of dates.

Comment: @Joe - I meant, are the numbers in the second list how the values appear in SAS?

Comment: Yep, if SAS doesn't detect the field as Date/Datetime it will show the underlying numerics (so, that).

Answer (score 2):

You can encourage SAS to convert the data as date during the import, although this isn't necessarily a panacea.

```
proc import file=whatever out=whatever dbms=excel replace;
  dbdsopts=(dbSasType=( datevar=date ) );
run;
```

where `datevar` is your date column name.  This tells SAS to expect this to be a date and to try to convert it.

See [So Your Data Are in Excel](http://www2.sas.com/proceedings/sugi31/020-31.pdf) for more information, or [the documentation](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/acreldb/63647/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a001371572.htm).

Answer (score 1):

From : http://www2.sas.com/proceedings/sugi29/068-29.pdf

> Times are counted internally in SAS as seconds since midnight and
>   date/time combinations are calculated as the number of seconds since
>   midnight 1 January 1960.
>
> Excel also uses simple numerical values for dates and times
>   internally. For the date values the difference with the SAS date is
>   only the anchor point. Excel uses 1 January 1900 as day one.

So add a constant.

EXAMPLES:

```
SAS_date = Excel_date - 21916;
SAS_time = Excel_time * 86400;
SAS_date_time = (Excel_date_time - 21916) * 86400;
```

Comment: Hi Justin, thank you for the reply., but I dint understand what I should do to get the date

Comment: The numbers you have listed as imported are the numbers of the Excel date-time code. You have imported an integer value, not a string that was parsed as a date.

Comment: Remember that Feb 29,1900 does not exist but is included in Excel/Microsoft data.

Comment: ok., I understnad., but can you tell me the best way of how do I go about converting it to sas date?

Comment: Can you give the full import code, or at least a more complete version than already posted?

Answer (score 0):

As Justin wrote you need to correct for the different zero date (SAS vs. Excel).

Then you just need to apply a format (if you want to get a date variable to do calculations):

```
want_date = have_date-21916;
format want_date date9.;
```

Or convert it to a string:

```
want_date = put(have_date-21916, date9.);
```

In either case you can choose the date format you prefer.